# How to set up alert on team discussion list in following scenario?

Tags: development, visual-web-part, alert, discussion-board

I am having the WebPart, which send a email to selected employees. Along with sending email, it is adding a discussion topic in OOTB Team discussion List. Adding this topic against the user to whom I sent email from webpart.And user id is maintained in Team Discussion List as well. Now It is requirement that, whenever any user put any comment on added discussion topic the respective emailed user should get alert/notification. I have set email out. Created alert in my Team discussion list. Where it asked me for the `Send to` email id. But how it manages new discussion topics and its email recipients and dynamically allocate to alert ?

Should I create a alert per topic from my C# WebPart itself ?

Comment: since it is a dynamic group that will be different from one discussion to another, the only way to do is to create it programmatically. Your code should be handling this

Comment: Thanks , Actually I don't have much idea about Alert in SharePoint. If I do this pragmatically then it will have number of Alerts per Discussion topics. Please correct me. Is that valid case if we have 1000 topics and same count of alerts in this scenario ? (may not at a time but to maintain them) ?

Comment: How about a workflow?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54167/how-do-i-set-up-alerts-per-discussion-board-in-sharepoint-2010